# Why can't i select a random element from this array, it keeps telling me i cannot convert from String[] to int

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

This has been annoying me for a little bit as i have no idea how to choose a random element from an array if random if the elements arent integers or doubles... i need a random element from the string array but math.random does not support this need. please help me, this program is due in a few hours. Thanks.

```
// multidimensional array
public static final String[][] arrCapitals  =
{   
    { "Alabama", "Montgomery" },        { "Alaska", "Juneau" },
    { "Arizona", "Phoenix" },           { "Arkansas", "Little Rock" },
    { "California", "Sacramento" },     { "Colorado", "Denver" },
    { "Connecticut", "Hartford" },      { "Delaware", "Dover" },
    { "Florida", "Tallahassee" },       { "Georgia", "Atlanta" },
    { "Hawaii", "Honolulu" },           { "Idaho", "Boise" },
    { "Illinois", "Springfield" },      { "Indiana", "Indianapolis" },
    { "Iowa", "Des Moines" },           { "Kansas", "Topeka" },
    { "Kentucky", "Frankfort" },        { "Louisiana", "Baton Rouge" },
    { "Maine", "Augusta" },             { "Maryland", "Annapolis" },
    { "Massachusettes", "Boston" },     { "Michigan", "Lansing" },
    { "Minnesota", "Saint Paul" },      { "Mississippi", "Jackson" },
    { "Missouri", "Jefferson City" },   { "Montana", "Helena" },
    { "Nebraska", "Lincoln" },          { "Nevada", "Carson City" },
    { "New Hampshire", "Concord" },     { "New Jersey", "Trenton" },
    { "New York", "Albany" },           { "New Mexico", "Santa Fe" },
    { "North Carolina", "Raleigh" },    { "North Dakota", "Bismarck" },
    { "Ohio", "Columbus" },             { "Oklahoma", "Oklahoma City" },
    { "Oregon", "Salem" },              { "Pennsylvania", "Harrisburg" },
    { "Rhode Island", "Providence" },   { "South Carolina", "Columbia" },
    { "South Dakota", "Pierre" },       { "Tennessee", "Nashville" },
    { "Texas", "Austin" },              { "Utah", "Salt Lake City" },
    { "Vermont", "Montpelier" },        { "Virginia", "Richmond" },
    { "Washington", "Olympia" },        { "West Virginia", "Charleston" },
    { "Wisconsin", "Madison" },         { "Wyoming", "Cheyenne" }
};

public static int chooseState(Random rand, String[][] arrCapitals)
{
    //create variable to hold random state
    String state = ("");
    //for loop
    //for(int i=0; i< arrCapitals.length; i++)
    //{
    int i1 = (int) (Math.random() * arrCapitals.length);
    //}

    return arrCapitals[i1];
    
}
```

Comment: `arrCapitals[i1]`, from the `String[][] arrCapitals`, returns what? What is the return type of `chooseState`?

Comment: It's not a string array, it's an array of array of strings, so `arrCapitals[i1]` will be a `String[]`. Your method is declared to return an `int`.

Comment: You aren't using `rand`. If you can't change the method signature, `return rand.nextInt(arrCapitals.length);` -- and if you can `public static String[] chooseState(String[][] arrCapitals) { return arrCapitals[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(arrCapitals.length)]; }`

Answer (score 1):

your **chooseState** method is **int**, but you are trying to return a **String** array, you can change the return type to **String**

```
public static String chooseState(Random rand, String[][] arrCapitals)
{
    //create variable to hold random state
    String state = "";
    //for loop
    //for(int i=0; i< arrCapitals.length; i++)
    //{
    int i1 = rand.nextInt(arrCapitals.length);
    //}

    return arrCapitals[i1][0]; // Return only the state name
}
```